# Conectar FTP a mi API de nodejs express?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, ftp

como puedo conectar un servidor FTP a mi aplicación de Nodejs utilizando express para generar links de descarga de archivos PDF?

o si existe un procedimiento mejor que un server FTP?
la idea es guardar la url de cada archivo en MongoDB y después darle acceso al usuario.

Comment: Investiga sobre multer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para conectar un servidor FTP a tu aplicación Node.js utilizando Express y generar links de descarga para archivos PDF, puedes seguir estos pasos generales:

1. **Instalar dependencias:**
   Asegúrate de tener instaladas las siguientes dependencias:

   ```bash
   npm install express basic-ftp
   ```

   `basic-ftp` es una biblioteca popular para trabajar con FTP en Node.js.
2. **Configurar Express:**
   Configura tu aplicación Express básica:

   ```javascript
   const express = require('express');
   const app = express();
   const port = 3000;

   app.listen(port, () => {
     console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
   });
   ```
3. **Conectar al servidor FTP:**
   Utiliza `basic-ftp` para conectarte al servidor FTP. Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

   ```javascript
   const FtpClient = require('basic-ftp');

   async function connectToFtp() {
     const client = new FtpClient.Client();
     try {
       await client.access({
         host: 'ftp.example.com',
         user: 'username',
         password: 'password',
       });
       console.log('Connected to FTP server');
       return client;
     } catch (err) {
       console.error(err);
       return null;
     }
   }

   // Llamada a la función
   const ftpClient = await connectToFtp();
   ```

   Asegúrate de reemplazar 'ftp.example.com', 'username' y 'password' con la información de tu servidor FTP.
4. **Generar links de descarga:**
   Cuando un usuario solicita descargar un archivo PDF, puedes generar un enlace de descarga y enviar el archivo al cliente. Aquí hay un ejemplo:

   ```javascript
   app.get('/descargar/:archivo', async (req, res) => {
     const archivo = req.params.archivo;

     // Descargar el archivo desde el servidor FTP
     if (ftpClient) {
       const remotePath = `/ruta/en/el/servidor/${archivo}`;
       const localPath = `./descargas/${archivo}`;

       try {
         await ftpClient.downloadTo(localPath, remotePath);
         console.log(`Archivo ${archivo} descargado localmente`);

         // Enviar el archivo al cliente
         res.download(localPath, archivo, (err) => {
           if (err) {
             console.error(err);
             res.status(500).send('Error al descargar el archivo');
           } else {
             console.log(`Archivo ${archivo} enviado al cliente`);
           }
         });
       } catch (err) {
         console.error(err);
         res.status(500).send('Error al descargar el archivo desde el servidor FTP');
       }
     } else {
       res.status(500).send('Error de conexión al servidor FTP');
     }
   });
   ```

   Asegúrate de ajustar las rutas y manejar los errores de manera apropiada.
5. **Manejar conexiones y desconexiones:**
   No olvides manejar las conexiones y desconexiones del cliente FTP correctamente:

   ```javascript
   // Cerrar la conexión FTP cuando la aplicación se cierra
   process.on('SIGINT', async () => {
     if (ftpClient) {
       await ftpClient.quit();
       console.log('Desconectado del servidor FTP');
     }
     process.exit();
   });
   ```

   Este código garantizará que la conexión al servidor FTP se cierre correctamente cuando la aplicación Node.js se detenga.

Este es un ejemplo básico para conectarse a un servidor FTP y proporcionar descargas de archivos PDF. Asegúrate de adaptarlo a tus necesidades específicas y agregar las capas de seguridad y manejo de errores necesarias para tu aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Para conectar tu aplicación Node.js a un servidor FTP y gestionar la descarga de archivos PDF, puedes utilizar la biblioteca basic-ftp.
Otras opciones que puede utilizar son firebase o ya bien utilizar los servicios de AWS.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).